# Display content without reloading page in php

Tags: php, ajax

I am using 2 div elements as tabber

**1)** search candidate

**2)** my list.In search candidate when i select some candidate ,than that candidate is added to selected_candidate table and displayed in my list div ,but to display it in my list i have to reload whole page ,how can i display it without reloading whole page

```
<div class="tabber" style="width: auto;">
<div <?php if(isset($_POST['submita'])){ echo "class=\"tabbertab tabbertabhide\"";}else{echo "class=\"tabbertab\"";} ?>>
<h3>SEARCH CANDIDATE</h3> 
//.....select candidate code.....//
</div>
<div <?php if(isset($_POST['searchsel_list'])){ echo "class=\"tabbertab tabbertabdefault\"";}else{echo "class=\"tabbertab\"";} ?>>
<h3>MY LIST</h3>

<div id="tabr">
<script>
$("td").removeAttr("style");​
</script>

<form method="post" action="csearch.php?epage=csearch" name="mylist">
   <div class="CSSTableGenerator">
   <table id="mylist_remark">
   <caption>SELECTED CANDIDATE LIST</caption>
   <!-- headings -->
    <tr>
      <th>REMARK</th>
      <th> <input name="delete_sel" id="delete_sel" value="DELETE" type="submit" class="button"/></th>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>CELL NO</th>
      <th>STATUS</th>
      <th>EMAIL ID</th>
      <th>LOCATION</th>
      <th>QAULIFICATION INFORMATION</th>
      <th>KIND OF WORK</th>
      <th>DETAILED CV</th>
    </tr>
<!-- /headings -->

<?php
if($mresult_set)
    {
    if (mysql_num_rows($mresult_set) == 0)
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td colspan=\"9\" ><p align=\"center\" class=\"message\"> <blink><span style=\"color:red;\" > NO CANDIDATE SELECTED</span></blink></p></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }

$j=0;
while($data_set1 = mysql_fetch_array($mresult_set))
    {  
        // $i=0;            
         if($data_set1['ca']=='')
         {
           $qua="";
         }
         else
         {
           $qua=$data_set1['ca'];
         }
         if($data_set1['cs']=='')
         {
           $qua="";
         }
         else
         {
           $qua.=",".$data_set1['cs'];
         }
         if($data_set1['cwa']=='')
         {
           $qua.="";
         }
         else
         {
           $qua.=",".$data_set1['cwa'];
         }
         if($data_set1['completed']=='')
         {
           $qua.="";
         }
         else
         {
         $qua.=", Completed(".$data_set1['completed'].")";
         }
         if($data_set1['persuing']=='')
         {
           $qua.="";
         }
         else
         {
           $qua.=", Persuing(".$data_set1['persuing'].")";
         }

        echo "<tr  >";
        echo "<td><input id={remark{$j}} type=\"text\" class=\"fancyText\" onkeyup=\"writeremark(this.id,{$data_set1['eid']},{$emprid});\" value=\"{$data_set1['remark']}\" maxlength=\"15\" placeholder=\"Write Remark\" /></td>";
        echo "<td style=\"text-align:center;\"><input id=\"listrow_sel{$j}\"  type=\"checkbox\" name=\"list_sel[]\" value=\"{$data_set1['eid']}|{$emprid}\" /></td>";
        echo "<td>{$data_set1['ename']} {$data_set1['lname']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$data_set1['ecell']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$data_set1['eposition']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$data_set1['eemail']}</td>";
        if($data_set1['ecity']=='')
        {
        echo "<td>{$data_set1['ecountry']}</td>";
        }
        else
        {
        echo "<td class=\"showmsg\" title=\"Country ={$data_set1['ecountry']}, State = {$data_set1['estate']} \" >{$data_set1['ecity']}</td>";
        }

       // echo "<td>{$data_set['ecountry']},{$data_set['estate']},{$data_set['ecity']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$qua}</td>";

        echo "<td>{$data_set1['other_work1']} {$data_set1['other_work2']}{$data_set1['other_work3']}{$data_set1['other_work4']} {$data_set1['other_work5']} {$data_set1['other_work6']} {$data_set1['other_work7']} {$data_set1['other_work8']} {$data_set1['other_work9']} {$data_set1['other_work10']}{$data_set1['other_work1e']} {$data_set1['other_work2e']} {$data_set1['other_work3e']} {$data_set1['other_work4e']} {$data_set1['other_work5e']} {$data_set1['other_work6e']} {$data_set1['other_work7e']} {$data_set1['other_work8e']} {$data_set1['other_work9e']} {$data_set1['other_work10e']}</td>";
        echo "<td><a style=\"cursor:hand;\"  href=\"detailcv.php?id={$data_set1['eid']}&flag=0\" target=\"_blank\" ><input style=\"cursor:auto;width:40px;\"  class=\"button\" name=\"cv\" type=\"button\" value=\"C V\" /></a></td>";              

        //echo "<td class=\"edit\" contenteditable=\"true\">Write Remark</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $j++;                       
        }
    }
?>
 <tr><td  colspan="10">
 <a href="<?php echo $listurl;?>"><img src="images/pdfdown.jpg" alt="Adobe Doc" width="42" height="42" title="Download List In PDF"/></a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <a id="showcand" href="<?php echo $listurl1;?>"><img src="images/excel.gif" alt="Excel Doc" width="42" height="42" title="Download List In Excel "/></a>
 <?php  ?>
 </td></tr>
</table></div>
</form>
</div>
```

[image: showing tabber]

In this Image i am showing tabber,when i click on MY list ,hoe can i load its form without loading whole page so that selected candidate will be visible,i came to know that it can be done using Ajax ,but i dont know how i can do it in my code

Comment: Use Ajax.............!!!

Comment: I have mentioned in question , I know it can be done using ajax but as I am new to ajax i am not getting how i do it ,any help will be appreciated

Comment: how? pick one of the million tutorials and follow it.

Comment: Follow this link:  http://phpcodeforbeginner.blogspot.in/2013/01/jquery-ajax-tutorial-and-example-of.html

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials for using AJAX and I don't think Stack Overflow is the best spot for such a general question. If you get stuck on a particular part of the implementation or show some attempt at using AJAX, then post on Stack Overflow.

Comment: thats called AJAX check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)

Comment: @Durga you can call ajax function on select candidate which refresh only data of your my list div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do with the help of ajax. for that you have to call ajax function on select candidate whom you want to add  to your list.

ajax function demo are as follows:

function getList(){

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "List.php", // file where you process the list.
data: {name:name1,sda:name2}, // post data you want to pass to the file for processing
success:function(data){

    //change the content of your mylist div here
}

});
}
```

you can try it.